# Gradle Scripts Syntax

Tags: gradle

I am learning Gradle these days and trying to understand how the syntax in gradle maps to the Gradle docs provided.

Can someone help me understand how the jarTaskName in the below snippet is derived? I can't see any attribute/method with the name jarTaskName in sourceSets class.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html

```
def integrationTest = sourceSets.create('integrationTest')
    configurations[integrationTest.implementationConfigurationName].extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation)
    configurations[integrationTest.runtimeOnlyConfigurationName].extendsFrom(configurations.testRuntimeOnly)
    
    
  def integrationTestJarTask = tasks.register(sourceSets.integrationTest.**jarTaskName**, Jar) {        
        archiveClassifier = 'integration-tests'
        from integrationTest.output
    }
```

Any documentation or quick pointers to understand above mapping will be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`jarTaskName` is documented in the API documentation to [SourceSet](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSet.html#getJarTaskName--). The documentation you linked is the DSL documentation which covers Gradle's build language.